# How do I set up code to dynamically delimit multiple times?

Tags: vba, excel, delimiter

I'm analyzing some data pulled from a website and right now it's formatted like this within a single cell in Excel, for example:

```
[2015-08-01--2010-01-01], Jerry Smith; [2009-12-31--2000-01-01], John Brown
```

where all of that is located in, let's say, A1.

I want to delimit it first by the semi-colon, then transpose the information, and then separate into columns the two date periods, so that way the final result for the example I listed above turns into a 2x3 cell grouping with the columns being 1. Start date 2. End date 3. Name

I've played around with some VBA code and I'm getting frustrated because I can't even figure out how to code the first step of delimiting by the semi-colon.

This is what I'm using so far:

```
    Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Selection.TextToColumns _
  Destination:=Range("A1"), _
  DataType:=xlDelimited, _
  TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
  ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
  Tab:=False, _
  Semicolon:=True, _
  Comma:=False, _
  Space:=False, _
  Other:=False, _
  OtherChar:=False, _

  End Sub
```

I know that this is the incorrect first step for delimiting by semi-colon, so what do I need to do to fix it and how do I approach the next steps I described?

Also, how can I write the code correctly such that it can adapt to 3+ name and date range pairings instead of only two like I listed in my example cell?

Comment: How many groupings are we talking on average?

Comment: Probably no more than 10 groupings of names with date ranges.  To give some context, they're mutual fund managers and their start and end dates for their tenures.

Comment: @jeeped answer should work, doing all in one action.

Answer (score 1):

Use variant arrays to first [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263365(v=vs.60).aspx) on the semi-colon, then split each piece on the comma. The dates are split/parse into actual dates and cell number formatting is applied to recreate the format of the original string dates.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim v As Long, vTMPs As Variant, vVALs As Variant, vDTs As Variant
    With ActiveSheet
        'split on semi-colon (e.g. Chr(59))
        vTMPs = Split(.Cells(1, 1).Value2, Chr(59))
        For v = LBound(vTMPs) To UBound(vTMPs)
            Debug.Print vTMPs(v)
            'split each piece on the comma
            vVALs = Split(vTMPs(v), Chr(44))
            'stuff it underneath and split the dates
            With .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                vDTs = Split(Mid(Trim(vVALs(LBound(vVALs))), 2, Len(Trim(vVALs(LBound(vVALs)))) - 2), "--")
                .Cells(1, 1) = DateSerial(Left(vDTs(0), 4), Mid(vDTs(0), 6, 2), Right(vDTs(0), 2))
                .Cells(1, 2) = DateSerial(Left(vDTs(1), 4), Mid(vDTs(1), 6, 2), Right(vDTs(1), 2))
                .Resize(1, 2).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
                .Offset(0, 2) = Trim(vVALs(UBound(vVALs)))
            End With
        Next v
    End With
End Sub
```

Each element of the final split is put into the next blank row in column A.

Comment: This is great, but what about the OP's third want, splitting the dates.  I am just curious how you would go about doing it as your code is always more compact than I would think possible.

Comment: @ScottCraner - yeah, I should have completed the final date trimming/split/conversion.

Comment: It was not meant as a criticism,  Again I would have done it different but the method I was thinking would have been a few more lines to get the same result.  I like to learn as well as help.  I appreciate your responses.

Comment: No worries. Don't mistake my terseness for deference. I write comments much as I do code; in as few words as possible. :)

Comment: I am going to spend some time reviewing this tomorrow to try and understand how it all works.  I really appreciate you posting this, and I wasn't expecting to get an answer this quickly.  I don't want to waste your time with my extremely limited knowledge, but I am curious.  Was my code that I was playing around with even on the right track or just completely wrong?

Comment: A series of [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) would work well if a column was inserted and the last one used `xlFixedWidth` and discarded the first, third and last field. However, a subsequent operation to bring the second record values down to the second row was what madfe the decision to move to variant arrays for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim strSplit() as string

strSplit =split(range("a1").value,";")
range("b1").value=strsplit(0)
range("b2").value=strSplit(1)
```

is the 1st bit :) then the same will apply to each of strSplit, using "," the 2nd time and will be date in 1 and name in the other

split("test show"," ") gives an array (0)="test" (1)="Show"

It can also be done using SUBSTITUTE and FIND/SEARCH in a formula, but can get tricky to track.